# Is LoginInterceptor Work in Struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am did the CRUD example with Struts2 without using Interceptor it work properly. Later I used Login Interceptor to maintain a session.But at that It showing exception to do any operation like edit,delete?
Exception is:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'push', field 'value': You must specify a value to push on the stack. 
>   below is my code:

My struts.xml

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="helloworld" extends="hibernate-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="mylogging"
             class="Demo.AuthenticationInterceptor">
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="mylogging" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
<!--some actions-->
</package>
</struts>
```

AuthenticationInterceptor:

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor
{
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception 
{       
    System.out.println("inside the interceptor()......new");
    Map session = ai.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    String name = (String) session.get("name");
    System.out.println("inside the session or loginaction=" + name);
    if ((session.get("name") != null) || ((session.get("name") == null))) {
        System.out.println("inside the session or loginaction ");
        return ai.invoke();
    } else {
        return "login";
    }
}
}
```

My Jsp Page To Register User and Edit also:

```
<body>

    <s:form action="saveOrUpdateUser" method="post">
        <s:push value="userdata">
            <s:hidden name="id" />                
            <s:textfield name="name" label="Enter Name"/>
            <s:textfield name="age" label="Enter Age"/>
            <s:textfield name="job" label="Enter Job"/>
            <s:submit />
        </s:push>
    </s:form>       
</body>
```

Stacktrace Report:

```
Struts Problem Report
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:
tag 'push', field 'value': You must specify a value to push on the stack. Example: person
tag 'push', field 'value': You must specify a value to push on the stack. Example: person - [unknown location]

File:   org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServletWrapper.java
Line number:    549
Stacktraces
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'push', field 'value': You must specify a value to push on the stack. Example: person - [unknown location]

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:361)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
```

Here Interceptor working.I mean when I logOut It's don't allow to do any operation but before logout if I do any operation it will throws exception.

Comment: I think problem in <s:push value="userdata"> code, where are you setting userdata in your jsp?

Comment: It stored in stack. If I remove Interceptor it's working every operation when I use Interceptor it's throws.

Comment: BTW why do you assign `session.get("name");` to `String name;` and then check `session.get("name");` again ?

Comment: @RomanC I added Stacktrace now see code once

Comment: @Prabha I saw the trace comes over JSP error not the interceptor error, why do you think the interceptor is a culprit?

Comment: Why are you using `<s:push>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed by @Noman the issue is you need to have the `userdata` object present in your valueStack when returned to JSP.

In case of `defaultStack`, action is fired, but in case of `LoginInterceptor`, it returns without reaching the action.

You can try to put the object `userdata` in prepare() method of action by implementing `Preparable` interface.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable{
   public void prepare(){
      userdata=...//initialize the object
   }
}
```

The working of the solution also depends on your interceptor-stack being used.

Comment: I added my struts.xml also is there need any change

Comment: I given total code in this link please go through that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650916/how-can-i-overcome-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Comment: I don't think that has something to do with this question.