# how work <s:push> tag in struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Below is my JSP page:

```
<s:form action="saveOrUpdateUser" method="post">
        <s:push value="userdata">
            <s:hidden name="id" />                
            <s:textfield name="name" label="Enter Name"/>
            <s:textfield name="age" label="Enter Age"/>
            <s:textfield name="job" label="Enter Job"/>
            <s:submit />
        </s:push>
</s:form>
```

How push tag working here I don't know. Here I want to know how this tag working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if you want to get the bean’s property, you may reference it like
 `<s:property`value=”#personBean.firstName” />. With “push” tag, 
you can push the “#personBean” to the top of the stack, and access the property directly

`<s:property value=”firstName” />`. Both are returned the same result, but with different access mechanism only.
The  tag pushes the value onto the stack. Subsequent  (and similar) tags check the stack in order, so whatever is pushed last will be queried first.

[for more click here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-push-tag-example/)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Struts 2 push tag example</h1>

<h4>1. Normal way</h4>
<s:bean name="com.mkyong.common.Person" var="personBean" />
First name : <s:property value="#personBean.firstName" /><br/>
Last name: <s:property value="#personBean.lastName" /><br/>

<h4>2. Push way</h4>
<s:push value="#personBean" >
First name : <s:property value="firstName" /><br/>
Last name: <s:property value="lastName" /><br/>
</s:push>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @404Thnak you very much. Is it possible to push the value from java class.If it possible how can I do.

Comment: this push tag is used to get values from the view

Comment: Because I am doing CRUD example with Login Interceptor. Without Interceptor it work properly but when I added Interceptor It throw exception. go through this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604000/is-logininterceptor-work-in-struts2

Comment: Please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604000/is-logininterceptor-work-in-struts2/20605134#20605134